# The formula "lookup" cannot find the value searched

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the table below, I am registering new products on the page named data. If the serial number in the page named "matbaaya_giden" has the largest 4 values, it is transferred to the page named "data" as 5. What I want is;

He needs to add -1 to the number 5 on the "data" page and bring the price for the product name and serial number match.
I use the formula below for this.

```
"=LOOKUP(2;1/((matbaaya_giden!$B$2:$B$2000=$B2)*(matbaaya_giden!$G$2:$G$2000=G2-1));matbaaya_giden!I$2:I$2000)"
```

This formula works in Excel. But I can't find the 2 value in "LOOKUP (2" in google tables and it gives an error. How can I make the formula work?

SHEET:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G2I52a7o15IRMzNHxRmkmZ2IuWpph0e4k7URWm3E6Gs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  explicitly state that it's a arrayformula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2;1/((matbaaya_giden!$B$2:$B$2000=$B2)*(matbaaya_giden!$G$2:$G$2000=G2-1));matbaaya_giden!I$2:I$2000))
```